# How can I include ! in named ranges or change the cells in a named range easier in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not 100% sure what i'm doing here as I'm pretty new to this, however what I am trying to do is have ranges with the same name on different sheets where I get "SheetX!Range" as the name of the range (which is possible in google sheets, but only if copied from another sheet).

Now the first couple of times I did this it automatically added "SheetX!" to the beginning if I entered a range name that already existed on another sheet as something like "Sheet1!Range" but after a while it just stopped doing that. I managed to work around that a few times because for a while I could change the cell of a named range and the name would stay the same, so I created a massive sheet with all of the potential named ranges I could possibly need and copied it for all of the sheets I would need. Now that's not really working either, because while occasionally it will change as intended, most of the time I just get "There is already a range with this name" cause it's trying to make a new range instead of changing the one that already exists. I know what I'm trying to do is possible because I have it working for one of my ranges on my sheet, it just doesn't want to work for the others despite the fact that I am doing the exact same thing as before (Unless I've just gone crazy after staring at these sheets for 5 hrs).

It is extremely important that the range is called "Sheet!Range" as I have a command that relies on that, so if anyone has any idea how I can do this I would really appreciate the help.

Sorry if my explanation of things is difficult to understand, I only learned how to use commands a few hours ago and before today all I could do on a spread sheet is type things and change the colors, so if you need me to clarify anything I've said I will gladly try.

Comment: I managed to work around the issue, but if you know a way to include ! in data range names other than as a copy of another sheet, then please share.